# Django sort the list - complex query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

These are my models

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewHeader = models.CharField(null=False,default="",max_length=200)

class ReviewRate(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(CompanyReview,null=False,default=0)
    isPositive = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

I would like to sort the reviews by the number of positive votes.

```
Review.objects.all().annotate(ss = Sum('rev__reviewrate__isPositive')).order_by('-ss')
```

This sorts the reviews by which has the maximum positive votes. But if a review has 2 positive and 2 negative votes, it comes before the review which has only one positive vote.

But I would like to sort them by (positive-negative) count.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this kind of things i think you need to add new field to your model like num_of_pos_votes then you can sort with this field